# List row number of each first value of a repeated series

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, worksheet-function

In a spreadsheet I have a column of this structure:

```
10.00
10.00
10.00
10.00
10.00
10.00
10.00
10.00
20.00
20.00
20.00
20.00
20.00
100.00
100.00
100.00
100.00
810.00
810.00
810.00
810.00
990.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
10.00
10.00
10.00
10.00
10.00
```

So lots of `10.00` followed by a couple of other values and then `10.00` starting again.

How can I get the row number of only the first `10.00` of each block of `10.00`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your lists starts in A2 (with something other than `10` in A1), in a spare column Row2 and copied down to suit:

```
=IF(AND(A2=10,A1<>A2),ROW(),"")
```

Comment: It's actually very close to what I want. Now how could I have all rows found from `row()` listed together under each other in a column?

Answer (score 1):

A small variation of the *pnuts* solution.

in **B1** enter:

```
=IF(A1=10,1,"")
```

In **B2** enter:

```
=IF(A2<>10,"",IF(A1=10,"",ROW()))
```

and copy down

Now to get a compact list, in **D1** enter:

```
=IFERROR(SMALL(B:B,ROW()),"")
```

and copy down:

[image]

Comment: That's exactly it, thanks a lot.

Comment: @TMOTTM  Consider upvoting *pnuts* since that was the original idea.